# Why does my popup script not work in ie9?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I don't even know where to start to fix the problem, please any help would be appreciated greatly.
Not sure if it is the innerHeight method or the scrollTop or something entirely different. The popup doesnt show up at all when viewed in ie9 but works fine in all other browsers and ie10 and up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function positionLightboxImage() {
        var popup = $('.popup'),
            closeBtn = $('.closeBtn'),
            overlay = $('.bgOverlay');
        overlay.hide();
        closeBtn.live('click', function () {
            popup.fadeOut();
            overlay.fadeOut();
        });
        popup.hide();
        var top = (window.innerHeight - popup.height()) / 2 - 200;
        var left = (window.innerWidth - popup.width()) / 2;
        console.log(top, left);
        popup.css({
            'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
                'left': left
        }).fadeIn();
        overlay.fadeIn();
        return false;
    }
    positionLightboxImage();
});
```

Comment: did you check you IE developer tools? what was this code error?

Comment: just try the same code when IE developer tools is open, I guess I faced the same issue and learns that IE9 only support console object when dev tools is opened. Can you please check when dev tools is on

Comment: You can view it  here: http://inhealthcds.com/

Comment: Yup, I verified the website and the reason is due to console object. I will post a detail answer to help you understand better.

Comment: where is the detailed answer? Did you post it or am i just slow and don't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE9, the `console` object is only available when developer tools is accessed. If developer tools is hidden, console object remains unavailable and if you navigate to new tab, you must also make sure developer tools is opened for that tab in order to fetch console object.

Comment: I checked your website and it is working as expected when developer tools is opened